# Is akka Scheduler singleton?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, lagom

If I have a cluster of 3 nodes, will below code create one scheduler or 3 schedulers for each node? I'm a little bit confused by the context from the documentation.

```
  system.scheduler.schedule(50.milliseconds, 5.seconds, wire[SchedulerRunnable])
```

> There you find the scheduler method that returns an instance of
>   akka.actor.Scheduler, this instance is unique per ActorSystem and is
>   used internally for scheduling things to happen at specific points in
>   time.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/scheduler.html

Answer (score 3):

It will create 3 schedulers, one on each node.

As James points out in the comments, one way to have just one scheduler for the cluster is to use a [cluster singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html) and set up your scheduling in `preStart` (so if the node with the singleton crashes and is recreated on another, your scheduling is re-started as well).

If you look at the [AuctionScheduler in the Lagom online auction example](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala/blob/24df3bb3d370a9d99f3b9250356abdc8fd91d621/bidding-impl/src/main/scala/com/example/auction/bidding/impl/AuctionScheduler.scala), you'll also see a slighly different approach to reliable scheduling, also using Akka's scheduler to trigger itself, and then getting the information what needs to be done from the read side.

Comment: Thanks! Then what is the best way to create one scheduler per cluster? Should I use singleton actor?

Comment: You need to create a cluster singleton, and start the scheduled task in its preStart method.